# Rename multiple files from their content

Tags: powershell, rename

I have a software exports multiple of files daily without extensions but it's actually text files. 
the files names are always as follow:

```
RESULTS10220309014171     
RESULTS10220309014231   
RESULTS10220309015778   
RESULTS10220309014131
```

The content of all the files (Hl7 protocol lines) is as follows:

```
MSH|^~\&|AppName||LIS||20190501004420||ORU^R01|1905011A91C6C2450|P|2.3|||NE|SU   
PID|1||602239||^^|||||||||||||   
PV1|1||||||||||||||||||   
....
```

So the first 3 lines are always same. 
I want to take the digits 602239 from the second line that starts with PID and rename the files with it to be:

```
602239   
552547   
336587   
696334
```

depends on the digits in the second line.

I've searched and tried multiple codes but it didn't work, i am a total beginner in PowerShell, so i will appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Get-ChildItem -Filter RESULTS*  | ForEach-Object { # Loop over files of interest
  $pidLine = (Get-Content $_.FullName -Head 2)[-1] # Extract 2nd line
  $newName = ($pidLine -split '\|+')[2]            # Get 3rd field
  $_ | Rename-Item -NewName $newName  -WhatIf      # Rename input file
}
```

<sup>Note: The [`-WhatIf` common parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_commonparameters#whatif) in the command above *previews* the operation. Remove `-WhatIf`  once you're sure the operation will do what you want.</sup>